# Find out a way to forbid user from posting a array without separated (,)

Tags: python, split

I want to forbid values of `phones` such as this:

## NOT ALLOWED EXAMPLE 1

```
phones = "00000000;00000000;00000000;"
```

## NOT ALLOWED EXAMPLE 2

```
phones = "00000000.00000000.00000000."
```

## NOT ALLOWED EXAMPLE 3

```
phones = "000000,,,,00"
```

and so on

## ONLY ALLOW

```
phones = "00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000"
```

Here's my attempt in code:

```
phones = "00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000"
phones = phones.split(',')
if len(phones) <= 100 and len(phones) >= 1:
    for item in phones:
        queue_sms(item, body, application_key, account_auth_token, ip_address):
else:
   print "Phone list is empty or exceeds limit"
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, you decalre the same varibale 'phones' twice

Comment: Read up on regular expressions.

Comment: Does your code not work? How do you know?

Comment: not related to your question, but the Pythonic way to write your if is `if 1<= len(phones) <= 100:`

Comment: The code works, the issue is that I want to avoid user from input characters that crashes my app or makes it work not properlly. I want to do is grab all this phones and loop then on a Redis Message Queue Job. "queue_sms" But I need validation before sending them to the job

Comment: if a user passes ,,,,,,,00000000,00000000,00000000 this will make a error for me. or What ever settings of string that does not fit my standard. I think I need a Mask that would return true, false if its compliant with String, String, String

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (1 <= len(phones) <= 100 and
        all(phone.isdigit() and len(phone) == 8 for phone in phones)):
```